# How do I use a conversion constructor with pointers?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a class `C` that can be converted to class `A` and a function that takes an `A*` as an argument. I want to call it with a `C*`, but I can't seem to get a conversion constructor to work. I get: `error: cannot convert ‘C*’ to ‘A*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void doSomething(A*)’`. What am I doing wrong?

```
class C {
};

class A {
public:
    A(C* obj) {}
};

void doSomething(A* object);

int main()
{
    C* object = new C();
    doSomething(object);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Conversion constructors* can only be defined for *user defined types*, in your case `A`. However, they do not apply to *fundamental types* as *pointers* like `A*`.

If `doSomething` was taking an `A const&` instead *(or simply an `A`)*, then the *conversion constructor* would be invoked as you expect.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I would rather not modify the signature of the function. Is there a way to make C++ do some tricks?

Comment: @Tim Mahoney: No, not at all, because it doesn't make sense. How would you get a pointer to an `A` if there is no `A` to point to?

Comment: @TimMahoney, if doSomething were to take a **const** pointer, and if you don't mind the warning the compiler will give, and if there are no ownership problems (alot of ifs, aren't there!?) than you can do something akin to the following http://ideone.com/YgaWua.

Comment: @K-ballo: Good point. I'll have to figure out something else.

Comment: @Dima Rudnik: Thats illegal _C++_.. Are you by any chance using _MSVC_ with microsoft specific extensions on?

Comment: @K-ballo, no idea. What compiler does ideone use?

Comment: @Dima Rudnik: That's _gcc_ ... mmh, I'm puzzled. I'd guess its legal then, though I'd be wary about it

Comment: @K-ballo, I don't disagree that it's ugly, unsafe and shuold not be done under most circumstances.. But how is it iilegal!? I modified `doSomthing` to accept a pointer to a const, and I pass it a pointer to a const (a temporary I created explicitly).

Comment: @K-ballo, you said you were puzzled, not that you agreed :)

Comment: Taking the address of a temporary is not legal C++, as the operand of the address-of operator must be an _lvalue_, and temporaries are (always?) _prvalues_. This can be worked around with a template like `template<typename T>T* addressof(T&& t) {return &t;}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you main requirement is to be able to call the existing doSomething function, then you can do this:

```
int main()
{
    C* object = new C();
    A a(object);
    doSomething(&a);
    // May need to delete object here -- depends on ownership semantics.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean that you want C to be a subclass of A:

```
class C : public A {
...
};
```

Comment: I wish. I can't modify the C class. However, it can be converted to A.

Comment: Then why do you expect a function that accepts class A to do with class C? 

You could do doSomething(reinterpret_cast<A *>(object)) or C casting doSomething((A *) object) but that would probably be wrong...

Comment: oops - sorry, I didn't notice you actually defined (or tried to define) a conversion constructor...